# VBA Excel Object Defined Error in code for exporting data to different server

Tags: vba, excel

I am a self-taught VBA Excel user and I am having trouble with some code that I am editing from a previous author for my needs. This code is supposed to look at a certain range of cells in the same column and export them with the respective tag in the next column over.

I keep getting an object defined error on the 29th line of the following code:

```
Public oServer As PISDK.Server

Public Sub SaveDataToPI()

Dim wsCurrent As Worksheet
Dim rValue As Double
Dim RowIndex As Integer
Dim strPITagName As String
Dim dtCurrent As Date
Dim blnSavedData As Boolean
'Dim bwLab As Double
'Dim bwAct As Double
'Dim bwDif As Double
'Dim MoistureLab As Double
'Dim MoistureAct As Double
'Dim MoistureDif As Double


With Application
    .Cursor = xlWait
    .StatusBar = "Sending Data To PI...."
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set wsCurrent = ActiveSheet

With wsCurrent
   'first column of data
    For RowIndex = 5 To 500
        If Len(EntryScreen2.Cells(RowIndex, 3).Value) < 1 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    ' Blank out error messages in column 4 if there
    EntryScreen2.Cells(RowIndex, 4).Value = ""

    Next
End With

With wsCurrent
   'first column of data
    For RowIndex = 5 To 500
        If Len(EntryScreen2.Cells(RowIndex, 3).Value) < 1 Then
            Exit For
        End If
        If Len(EntryScreen2.Cells(RowIndex, 2).Value) > 0 And Len(EntryScreen2.Cells(RowIndex, 3).Value) > 0 Then
            'Save Data To PI
            dtCurrent = wsCurrent.Range(wsCurrent.Cells(2, 2), wsCurrent.Cells(2, 2)).Value
            Call SavePIData(EntryScreen2.Cells(RowIndex, 3).Value, EntryScreen2.Cells(RowIndex, 2).Value, dtCurrent, RowIndex)
            EntryScreen2.Cells(RowIndex, 2).Value = ""
            blnSavedData = True
        End If

    Next
End With

If blnSavedData = True Then MsgBox "Data Saved to PI, Check Column D for Errors"

With Application
    .Cursor = xlDefault
    .StatusBar = "Ready...."
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub


Public Function GetServer(szServer As String) As PISDK.Server

'Dim oServer As PISDK.Server
Dim oCon    As Object

Set oServer = Servers(szServer)

On Error Resume Next
If oServer.Connected = False Then
    oServer.Open
End If

On Error GoTo 0

If oServer.Connected = False Then
    Set oCon = CreateObject("PISDKdlg.Connections")

    On Error Resume Next
    oCon.Login oServer, , , False
End If

Set GetServer = oServer
End Function

Public Sub SavePIData(strPITagName As String, dblValue As Double, dtCurrent As Date, RowIndex As Integer)

Dim oTag        As PIPoint
'Dim oServer     As Server

On Error GoTo Error

Set oServer = GetServer("pksfpi")

Set oTag = oServer.PIPoints(strPITagName)

'Send Data to database
oTag.Data.UpdateValue dblValue, dtCurrent

Set oTag = Nothing
Exit Sub
Error:
EntryScreen2.Cells(RowIndex, 4).Value = Err.Description

End Sub

Public Sub SaveEditedDataToPI(strPITagName As String, dtCurrent As Date, dblValue As Double)

Dim oTag        As PIPoint
'Dim oServer     As Server

On Error Resume Next
'    strPITagName , dtCurrent, rValue

Set oServer = GetServer("pksfpi")

Set oTag = oServer.PIPoints(strPITagName)


'Send Data to database
oTag.Data.UpdateValue dblValue, dtCurrent, dmReplaceOnlyDuplicates

Set oTag = Nothing

End Sub
```

If you find anything else wrong in my code, feel free to let me know so that I don't run into anymore problems.

Thanks!!

Comment: What is `EntryScreen2`? You have a `With wsCurrent ... End With` block but you never reference it.

Comment: @BigBen the EntryScreen2 is the name of the sheet in the VBA properties window. So instead of Sheet2 or Sheet3, it's labeled as EntryScreen2

Comment: So you don't need the `wsCurrent` then... Which line exactly throws the error?

Comment: So I changed the name of the EntryScreen2 to what my actual VBA properties window shows and the code runs (I did a stupid thing and copied the code from another spreadsheet thinking that it would work for mine without any changes). Now to just get the permissions I need in order to save the data on the server it needs to be on. Thanks for your help! @BigBen